# Finding Partial Derivative in two ways

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am supposed to find $f_x(0,0)$ of  $\frac{5x^2y}{x^4+y^2}$, **EDIT: which has a defined value of $0$ at $(0,0)$**.

The way I did it, I first found the general expression for $f_x(x,y)$, which is $$f_x(x,y) = \frac{10xy(x^4+y^2)-5x^2y(4x^3)}{(x^4+y^2)^2}= \frac{10y^3x-10yx^5}{(x^4+y^2)^2}$$ Now, it is apparent that $f_x(0,0)$ is not defined, for the denominator; $(x^4+y^2)^2$ equals $0$. Thus, the partial derivative does not exist.

However, the solution says,

$$f_x(0,0)= \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(\Delta x,0)-f(0,0)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\frac{0}{\Delta x ^4} -0}{\Delta x} = 0$$

Essentially, they substituted $0$ in for $x$ before taking the limit, and as a result, were able to get $0$. But why does my method not work, of finding the general form of the partial derivative and THEN substituting $0$?

Comment: yep. You are right. To make you feel more confident, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+%5Cfrac%7B5x%5E2y%7D%7Bx%5E4%2By%5E2%7D+at+(0,0)

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen I forgot to add an important piece of information before you posted. But I still do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

If we want to calculate the partial derivative of $f(x,y)$ at any point away from the origin (0,0), we can use the usual formulas. However, if we want to calculate $\frac{∂f}{∂x}(0,0)$, we have to use the definition of the partial derivative,which is $$\frac{∂f}{∂x}(a,b) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a,b+h) -f(a,b)}{h}$$ Because there are no formulas that apply at points around which a function definition is broken up in the way that causes the function to be undefined.

Therefore,$$\frac{∂f}{∂x}(0,0)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}\\
  =\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}\\=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{5h^2(0)}{h^4+0}-0}{h}=0
  $$

Comment: It looks like you meant $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a, b) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + h, b) - f(a, b)}{h}$$